# Mapping a real/proposed folder and file structure to xml and eventually database

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, directory-structure

For this question the technology set is C# 4.0, and SQL Server 2008. This feature will be a part of a Visual Studio Extension.

We need to implement a strategy which will allow our users to define how a particular folder/file structure might look like. A UI will be provided that will allow users to add  "folder(s)" or  "file(s)" (type irrelevant) within these folders. We then need to store this schema as defined by the user in a data structure and eventually validate it against a real folder structure (provided later). So a user comes in, uses our UI to define how a folder structure would look like. We take his/her definition and store it in a DB somewhere. Later on it is possible for the user to do these

**Validation**
The user points us to the network share or any location which has been setup as per this defined structure. We then go and validate the defined schema against the actual location.

**Make it like this**
The user points us to a folder where all the files defined in his schema are kept. We then parse all the files and restructure them as per the user's schema definition in various folders.

**Actions with each "node"**
In the defined schema it is also possible for a user to associate an action with each node - defined as a set of files. SO the user can group 5 files under a folder say A and associate an action of "Move this to X location". It is not really important to understand how these actions will be triggered (possibly from the same UI where user defines this schema). The key concept is of being able to logically group files together and define an action on them.

There are a few different ways I can think of approaching this problem. Obviously XML comes to mind as the first choice. However the problem with storing Xml in DB is that it gets tiresome to properly query XML in a DB column. Not to mention the additional size of an XML document due to all tag names etc.

This is a bit of an open ended problem and I wanted to present this to the geniuses here at SOF to get a few good ideas going!

Comment: why does the xml need to be stored in a db?  Just give the files names that are id's and use the id's as a foreign key in the db as reference.

Comment: This system will support thousands of clients each with his own "set of schemas". Users can keep coming back to a schema once defined and process multiple input sets (locations) against it.